Best way to create large volume of tables
I need to perform stress testing of Salesforce when connecting from a metadata catalog or other application.  We want to create hundreds of different Salesforce tables that are exposed in Data Cloud that we can extract metadata from and query.
I managed to create a script that generates the tests CSVs (each CSV represents a table) and use the Metadata API and Bulk API to create custom objects/fields and load the CSVs.  The problem is I have not found a programmatic way to set the field-level security for the custom fields or expose the objects in Data Cloud.
I have also considered uploading the CSVs to S3 and creating an S3 data stream for every CSV (assuming I can also use the metadata and other APIs to do that).
Is there a prescribed way of creating a large number of tables/objects/streams and upload associated data via an API (without manual intervention)?

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/customer-360-audiences-data-ingestion-and-modeling is a good start
